# A pattern for categories of objects with the same data?

Tags: java, database, oop, design-patterns

I've been working on a project and have come across a puzzling question about how to approach a design (object-oriented). I have different categories of objects, for example, `Employee`, `Groundskeeper`, `Customer`, etc. that have the same data: a name, ID number, etc. So far, I have made a single interface, `Person`, and each of these different categories `extends` this interface. The issue arises when I try to retrieve the data.

If I want to retrieve only object of one of the categories, say a `Customer`, I have to make a new method, `getCustomers()`. If I want to get all of the employees, I have to make another similar method called `getEmployees()`. This continues for each of the categories. The problem is that the methods have almost identical implementation, because the data for each category is the same. The only difference is that each returns only a specific category.

Is there a better way of doing this, where I need only one method, where I am not repeating myself (in the spirit of DRY)?

Note: these categories must be separate, because, down the road, I need to place each in its own table in the database, so there must be a separation of categories at some point.

**Possible Solution:**

I have found a solution to this issue, and your suggestion helped a great deal in finding it (@Adam me). Instead of making separate method calls for each category, I used a generic method, where the category is supplied as the generic parameter to the method. Also, the class of the category is supplied as a key to the database table.

For example, the signature for obtaining a `Person` of a specific category would be:

```
public <T extends Person> Queue<T> getPersons (Class<T> key) {...}
```

And to call the method, for `Customer` let's say, the call would be:

```
Queue<Customer> customers = dataStore.<Customer>getPersons(Customer.class);
```

The `Class<T>` is just used a key, and inside the `getPersons(...)` method, there is a `Map` that maps the class to a table in the database (`Map<Class<? extends Person>, String>)`. Therefore, when the class of the `Person` is supplied (`Customer`, `Employee`, etc.), a lookup is performed on the map, and then the data is retrieved from the database table associated with that class.

Although it is different than the suggested answers, I greatly appreciate your response: They led me in the right direction for the solution.

Comment: You call it interface, but what you really mean is that `Person` is an `abstract class`, right? About those methods, `getCustomers()`, `getEmployees()`, where would they be (what class)?

Comment: Have you thought about filter-based search?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. What I mean is that `Person` is an abstract class, with methods, `getName()`, `getId()`, etc. Then `Employee`, `Customer`, etc. extend this abstract class. A different class has the methods `getCustomers()` and the like, and retrieves all the customers (from a database, let's say).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a method that takes the class name you want to be returned as a parameter. Any class that inherits a Person is still a Person object so you can still refer to them as such.

```
public Person (String typeOfPerson) {
  return all persons where:      
    person.getClass().getName().equals(typeOfPerson);
}
```

Comment: This led me in the correct direction. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this implementing a filter-based structure to get just the desired objects.

```
interface Person { }

class Employee implements Person { }
class Costumer implements Person { }

interface Criteria {
    public boolean match(Person p);
}

class ClassNameCriteria implements Criteria {
    private String className;

    public TypeCriteria(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

    public function match(Person p) {
        return person.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(this.className);
    }
}

class Client {
    private Collection<Person> persons;
    public Collection<Person> getByCriteria(Criteria c) {
        Collection<Person> col = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for(Person p : persons) {
           if (c.match(p)) { 
               col.add(p);
           }
        }
        return col
    }
}

Client client = new Client();
// Adds some persons...
Criteria c = new ClassNameCriteria("Employee");
Collection<Person> = client.getByCriteria(c); // If you need, you can safely cast to Collection<Employee>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution:**

I have found a solution to this issue, and your suggestion helped a great deal in finding it (@Adam me). Instead of making separate method calls for each category, I used a generic method, where the category is supplied as the generic parameter to the method. Also, the class of the category is supplied as a key to the database table.

For example, the signature for obtaining a `Person` of a specific category would be:

```
public <T extends Person> Queue<T> getPersons (Class<T> key) {...}
```

And to call the method, for `Customer` let's say, the call would be:

```
Queue<Customer> customers = dataStore.<Customer>getPersons(Customer.class);
```

The `Class<T>` is just used a key, and inside the `getPersons(...)` method, there is a `Map` that maps the class to a table in the database (`Map<Class<? extends Person>, String>)`. Therefore, when the class of the `Person` is supplied (`Customer`, `Employee`, etc.), a lookup is performed on the map, and then the data is retrieved from the database table associated with that class.

Although it is different than the suggested answers, I greatly appreciate your response: They led me in the right direction for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a design from Bloch's Effective java book (forgot which item). It makes use of both worlds and takes the best from both:

- IPerson: is the interface with the getter and setter you want
- AbstractPerson implements IPerson: is called a **Skeleton** class and has fields and accessors to it, or any code you want to share.
- Subclasses (e.g. you Customer) extends AbstractPerson: Any specific additions to your Person.

The **beauty** of this solution is that you have some shared code in your Skeleton class, but are **independent** of it. Some new class which already extends some other class can implement the interface and thus become an IPerson as well.